# verify email and password field - react native

Tags: react-native

good day, I have a fetch where I bring my data from my api, everything works but I need to validate an if and if the email and password are correct, enter the if, since I have the example but with default data `correo == "pepe@gmail.com" && password == "12345678"`, I need it to be, for example, email=true, that is, if the email is correct and the password, enter the if and not place default data such as: pepe@gmail.com and 12345678

```js
const {data} = await cafeApi.post<LoginResponse>('/usuarios/login.php',{correo,password});
        
        if(correo == "pepe@gmail.com" && password=="12345678"){
            dispatch({
                type: 'signUp',
                payload: {
                    token: data.token,
                    user: data.usuario
                }
            });
        }else{
            console.log(data);
        
            Alert.alert("no es pepe")
    }
```

Comment: Do you need verification only in login? Or do you have another form fields to be validated? If yes I would suggest to use library such as yup etc.

Comment: i just need verification